# Find Non needed vertex in a graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, connectivity, vertices

Is there any known algorithm that:
for a given ***connected graph*** G defined by a list of vertices V and list of edges E detrmines which vertices can be removed while the ***graph will still be connected***?

Thanks for your help.

***N.B:***

1. I mean by connected graph that for every two vertices V1 and V2
   there is a path between them.
2. algorithm complexity is an issue

Comment: Are all these found vertices removed or only one vertex is removed at a time?

Comment: One vertex is removed at a time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a well-known problem. Such vertices are called graph articulation points. It is possible to find them all in `O(V + E)` using depth-first search. It is easy to find a description of this algorithm(for example, here: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/articulation-points-or-cut-vertices-in-a-graph/).